# How to manage looping on this list on Applscript?

Tags: list, loops, applescript, records

The list is in the form of:-

0:
https://url
1:
https://url
..... And so on.

How could I loop on this list. So I could fetch the number first without ":" and type it somewhere then fetch the url that comes after that number and type it elsewhere. Then end repeat if the list is over.
Or should I use records instead?

I am still a beginner using AppleScript. I tried many commands I mixed up but the computer keeps running the script nonestop and the activity monitor shows the applescript using 100% of the processor and huge amount of ram. 
Appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Show.Your.Code. The *list* you are talking about seems to be a record

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define what your list really looks like very well so I made an assumption on my answer below. If I was wrong, hopefully my answer will at least point you in the right direction. (or if I've gotten it wrong, but you can choose to reformat it to the way I suggested, that could still help)

```
on run
    set theList to {"0:http://apple.com", "1:http://google.com"} -- my guess at what your list looks like.
    repeat with anItem in theList
        set anItem to anItem as string
        set itemParts to myParseItem(anItem)
        set tID to the_integer of itemParts as integer
        set tURL to the_url of itemParts as string
    end repeat
end run

on myParseItem(theItem)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set delimitedList to every text item of theItem

    set newString to (items 2 thru -1 of delimitedList as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}

    set theInt to item 1 of delimitedList
    set theURL to newString as string

    return {the_integer:theInt, the_url:theURL}
end myParseItem
```